# Regex lookbehind with linebreaks?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to extract content bewteen boundaries using lookahead/behind like this:

```
Filename: myfile.txt
Message: myMessage
Time:...
```

I want to extract what's between the filename and the time using regex:

```
(?<=.txt).*(?=Time)
```

But it does not work as linebreaks are not taken. What can I change to match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you forgot to escape the `.` in `.txt`.

```
/(?<=\.txt).*(?=Time)/
```

Secondly, you don't actually capture ("extract") anything.

```
/(?<=\.txt)(.*)(?=Time)/
```

Then you need to tell Perl that `.` should match every character, not every character except newlines.

```
/(?<=\.txt)(.*)(?=Time)/s
```

And there you go. You could improve it a little by only matching from the start to the end of a line:

```
/(?<=\.txt\n)(.*)^(?=Time)/sm
```

Btw, there doesn't seem to be any reason to use lookarounds in this case.

Comment: I'd put the anchor outside the lookahead: `^(?=Time)`  Then the lookahead will only get applied at the beginning of a line.  Your way it has to be tried at every position.  That can get pretty expensive if the input is at all large, especially in combination with `(.*)` in `/s` mode.  But +1 anyway, if only for the anti-lookaround advice. ;)

Comment: @Alan Moore, Sage advice incorporated.

Comment: Nice step-by-step answer! +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `.` match a newline, you need to enable the `/s`, which makes the entire string be treated as a single line.

In addition, you probably should not use look-arounds for this.  Generally, they should only be used when you want to get overlapping matches.  They can produce unexpected results when used to simply get part of a match.

The standard way to get a part of a match is to use capturing subgroups:

```
if (/\.txt(.*?)Time/s)
{
   print "The between portion is:\n$1";
}
```

Comment: You might want to use a reluctant quantifier: `(.*?)`  It probably won't make a noticeable difference, but if the input turns out to be very large you'll be glad you did.

Comment: And kudos for demonstrating the sensible (i.e., non-lookaround) approach. ;)